# Proguard rules -keep vs -keepclassmembers vs -keepclasseswithmembers

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Reading [proguard rules](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#keep)

I found my self facing three terms that seemed to be very similar 
`keep` `keepclassmembers` `keepclasswithmembers`

I couldn't understand the difference between those three rules, Can someone explain the difference a bit better and maybe an example as well

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1)  keep -  preserve classes

2)  keepclassmembers  - preserve class members such as fields & methods

3)  keepclasseswithmembers  - preserve classes if they satisfy certain conditions based on members

**Examples**

1) preserve all classes extending android.app.Activity

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
```

2) preserve all member ( static field )  named CREATOR  on the condition if they are implementing android.os.Parcelable

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable { 
static ** CREATOR; 
}
```

3) preserve all classes if they have constructor ( mentioned below as init ) with parameters( Context, AttributeSet ) or ( Context, AttributeSet , int ) .

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * { 
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
} 

-keepclasseswithmembers class * { 
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
}
```

Comment: @john-salib Can you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110559/r8-and-proguard-rules